How to permute array elements by shifting and then undoing?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void permute(int arr[],int len){
    //if(len==1) cout << arr[fixed];
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
        if(len==0) return;
        for(int j=i; j<len-1; j++){
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        }
        permute(arr, len-1);
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n = 3;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cin >> arr[i];
    permute(arr, n);
}

I know the swap method of code for permutating elements. I am trying to implement this method in which I am printing every element as I get it and then shift all the elements after that by one place below.
But because of it, the whole array itself changes.
How do I get my previous array back when I complete one iteration, just as we get the array by unswapping the swapped elements.

How about keeping a copy of the original ? Also better use std::vector (or std::array) instead of C arrays. And note that C++ does not support VLAs (int arr[n]).

Your inner for loop destroys arr[i], obviously, but it seems that undoing that would be the relatively simple matter of storing that element in a local and putting it back after reversing the shift.

see also std::next_permutation

Inside the loop, i is always less than len. Therefore, since i starts out at 0, the statement if(len==0) return; is a nop.

In current C++ permute shoud have the signature : void permute(std::span<int> values). What you are doing is "C" style coding

I wonder what the reason is for the if(len==0) return; instruction. You never modify len within the for(int i=0; i<len; i++) { ... } body, so you would need len==0 at the beginning for the if(...) return; to perform return. But if you have len==0 you will not enter the for loop, because i, initialized to zero, can not be less than len being zero itself. So... what's the reason for that void if-return in your code?

There is no need to undoing here, you just need to rotate array:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void permute(int arr[], int len, int total_len) {

    if (len > 1) {

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            permute(arr, len - 1, total_len);

            // <<<
            int buff = arr[0];
            for (int j = 0; j < len - 1; j++) {
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            }
            arr[len - 1] = buff;
            // >>> - It can be simplified:
            //std::rotate(arr, arr + 1, arr + len);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int j = 0; j < total_len; j++)
            cout << arr[j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    const int n = 3;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> arr[i];
    permute(arr, n, n);
}

The same thing, but using std::array class and without passing the total_len:
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, size_t N>
void permute(array<T, N> arr, size_t len) {

    if (len > 1) {
        auto rem_len = len - 1;
        auto first = arr.begin();
        auto mid = first + 1;
        auto last = first + len;
        while (len--) {
            permute(arr, rem_len);
            rotate(first, mid, last);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (const auto& a : arr)
            cout << a << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    const size_t n = 3;
    array<int, n> arr;
    for (auto& a : arr) cin >> a;
    permute(arr, n);
}


Following on from wohlstad's and 500 - Internal Server Error's
comments, keeping a copy of the original array is a solution your problem.
Here's how i have done it:
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void permute(int arr[], int len){
    int copy[len];                          //new
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
        if(len==1) return;
        memcpy(copy, arr, len*sizeof(int)); //new
        for(int j=i; j<len-1; j++){
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        }
        permute(arr, len-1);
        memcpy(arr, copy, len*sizeof(int)); //new
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n = 3;
    
    int arr[n];
    cout << "Enter Values" << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < n;){
        arr[i] = cin.get();
        if (arr[i] != ' ' && arr[i] != '\n'){
            ++i;
        }
    }
    
    permute(arr, n);
}

I have also changed the base condition to check for len == 1, which follows from tbxfreeware comment:

Inside the loop, i is always less than len. Therefore, since i starts out at 0, the statement if(len==0) return; is a nop

I also changed how values are input into the array (because the one used in the question was not working for me).
Here is a test run of the code:
Enter Values
A B C
65 66 67
67 66

66 65 67
67 65

67 65 66
66 65

This somewhat gives all the permutations in the array (but each iteration after the first, at a given depth of the recursion, seems to forget about the characters that come before it).
To fix this, i added another array that stores the entire permutation then prints it out once len == 1
void permute(int arr[], int len, int permutation[], int depth){
    int copy[len];
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        permutation[depth] = arr[i];
        if(len==1){
            for(int j = 0; j < depth + 1; ++j){
                cout << permutation[j] << ' ';
            }
            return;
        }
        memcpy(copy, arr, len*sizeof(int));
        for(int j=i; j<len-1; j++){
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        }
        permute(arr, len-1, permutation, depth + 1);
        memcpy(arr, copy, len*sizeof(int));
        cout << endl;
    }
}

This is called as follows:
int permutation[n];
permute(arr, n, permutation, 0);

And here is a test run
Enter Values
A B C
65 66 67
65 67 66

66 65 67
66 67 65

67 65 66
67 66 65

